# Django creates but doesn't updates object with get_or_create() method

Tags: django

I have a model that looks like this and I try to update field `average_entry_price` but my problem is that there is no update from value 7.0 to 7074.0 although the object is created. As you can see `created` return a `False`.

There is no error message and I think the syntax is correct since I first try to match on fields `market` and `account`, which seems to work fine because the object is created correctly at the beginning, and then I say to Django update the remaining field `average_entry_price`.
Am'I missing something here?

```
print(type(market))
print(type(a))
print('new value is', position['price'])
obj, created = Position.objects.get_or_create(
                market=market,
                account=a,
                defaults={
                    'average_entry_price': position['price']
                },
            )
print(obj.average_entry_price)
print(created)
```

Then it returns:

```
<class 'marketsdata.models.Market'>
<class 'trading.models.Account'>
new value is 7074.0
7.0
False
```

models.py

```
class Position(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='position',
                                null=True
                                )
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='position',
                               null=True
                               )

    average_entry_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,
                                              decimal_places=1,
                                              null=True
                                              )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Positions"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.market)
```

Comment: Try creating a method in your model `def get_price(self): return self.average_entry_price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As name states [get_or_create](http://get_or_create()) does not update

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
>   created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

you probably want [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the created or
>   updated object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

```
obj, created = Position.objects.update_or_create(
                market=market,
                account=a,
                defaults={
                    'average_entry_price': position['price']
                },
            )
```

Comment: OMG I had a bad night I didn't noticed this, thanks!